# 3D plotting software for Mac

Tags: mac

I know I can use Matlab for this. But my question is that is there any dedicated 3D plotting software for Mac, which can to generate surface and contour plots from a spread sheet file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**Google Sketchup**](http://sketchup.google.com/intl/en/index.html), 3D modeling software.

Free and pro versions...

> For Windows XP/Vista/7 & Mac OS X (10.5+)

Answer (score 0):

[R](http://www.r-project.org/) could be a nice alternative, check some of the possibilities of [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/), [rgl](http://rgl.neoscientists.org/about.shtml) and [scatterplot3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/).

If you need a dedicated program for your purposes, you could write your customized functions and call the R script from command line, or if you insist on using GUI, that could be also achieved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like something I won't. Basically, MATLAB is a very inefficient program. Although the output is quite good. I'll try R.

Answer (score 0):

You might also checkout [Gnuplot](http://www.lee-phillips.org/info/Macintosh/gnuplot.html) for the Mac.